# Handle multiple events with the same event handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a notification, and I want to dismiss it with a click anywhere on the screen, or any keypress. Currently, I've got two methods that look like this

```
private void Dismiss(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(dismissable && dismissSeconds<=0)
    {
        FadeOut();
    }
}

private void Dismiss(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (dismissable && dismissSeconds <= 0)
    {
        FadeOut();
    }
}
```

I know that if the two objects send the same args type you can just select the same event handler in the properties window but since one returns KeyEventArgs and the other returns MouseEventArgs, that doesn't work.

If I'm not using the args anyway though, can I get rid of this duplicate code? Or am I going to confuse the designer if I start messing about?

Comment: I know this is a pretty minor cleanup, but I'm trying to develop good habits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extract the code to a new method that you call from the two event handlers:

```
private void Dismiss(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Dismiss();
}

private void Dismiss(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Dismiss();
}

private void Dismiss()
{
    if (dismissable && dismissSeconds <= 0)
    {
        FadeOut();
    }
}
```

Note that you *could* declare a single event handler, by specifying `EventArgs` as the parameter type:

```
private void Dismiss(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dismissable && dismissSeconds <= 0)
    {
        FadeOut();
    }
}
```

This way, the handler would be compatible with both events. However I wouldn't recommend doing that, because I think it's cleaner to keep things clearly separated. If someday you need to do something slightly different for the mouse event and the keyboard event, you will have more refactoring to do if you used a single handler.

Comment: I'd thought of the first way, but I thought it could be a bit cleaner. I think I'm going to do the second way, because it's more minimal and I'm fairly sure the event won't need to change. Thanks man

Comment: Also, I assume this works because both MouseEventArgs and KeyEventArgs inherit from EventArgs?

Comment: @NathanTempelman, yes. A method that accepts an EventArgs will also accept a MouseEventArgs or KeyEventArgs, so the signature is compatible with both delegate types.